# Making the JQuery Validation plugin evaluation non-lazy

Tags: jquery-validate

According to the documentation for the JQuery validation plugin:

> the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages

Is there any way to display the messages as the user tabs through the form?

Cheers

Comment: How about validating the form immediately after load via script. $(function() { $('#myForm').validate(); $('#myForm').valid(); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default [`onfocusout`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to do more eager/pre-submit validation you want, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("form").validate({
    rules: { ...rules... },
    messages: { ...messages... },
    onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }
  });
});
```

The [default `onfocusout` looks like this](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js), disabling the `blur` validation until after it's been submitted once:

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
  if ( !this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element)) ) {
    this.element(element);
  }
}
```